# Writing my first Dynamic Business Rule

Tags: business-rules, endeca

I've been working with Endeca at arms length for three years. Now I need to write my first dynamic business Rule.

I have records with a property, say "ActiveField", as a business Rule I need to take the value of "ActiveField" and return the records that match it. I'll restrict it to 20 with the Style.

I've read about writing Dynamic Business Rules, and I've gone through the dialogue box. I can't find where I'd need to write the logic that makes the matches. If it was SQL I expect I'd type in:

```
SELECT record.name record.id Where record.ActiveField = @ActiveField
```

I appreciate Endeca might not work like this, or convey this functionality in drop-down boxes which are written to XML config files.

But I can't find any hint of this level of complexity in the documentation; I'm probably missing something since this is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Business rules are triggered by search / navigation states, not by records.

Rules can be created in several places depending on your deployment:

1 Developer studio

2 Merchandising Workbench (page builder or rule manager)

3 Experience Manager (which has replaced Merchandising
    workbench in the most recent releases).

In any of these locations you can set a trigger for your rule which can be either a search term or a dimension value(s), or combination of the two.

The actual records returned do not effect whether or not the rule is triggered. At that point your application has to take over a do something with the rule.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks I am aware that Business rules are only triggered on searches.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. The search will return matching searches regardless of the business rules.